# DOMDebugger.getEventListeners doesn't return backendNodeId

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-devtools-protocol

I followed the doc https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOMDebugger/#method-getEventListeners to try DOMDebugger.getEventListeners.
I can get the array of event listeners but there is no backendNodeId in each object. But I need the backendNodeId to get the node object. Anything I'm missing here?

[image]

chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId:tabId}, "DOMDebugger.getEventListeners", {objectId, depth: -1}, (listeners) => {
console.log(listeners);
});

Thanks!